# How can I install lxml 3.5.0 in python 3.6 on windows 7?

Tags: lxml, python-3.6

How can I install lxml 3.5.0 in python 3.6 on windows 7?
I want to fetch old tweets from twitter using twitter streaming API, and for that I went through https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python.
In that it has suggested to install lxml 3.5.0 and pyquery 1.2.0. Though pyquery was installed successfully, installation of lxml showed error.So,from where can I download lxml 3.5.0 for python 3.6?

Answer (score 0):

lxml 3.5.0 is available till python version 3.4 - check this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.5.0

If you want to install lxml 3.8.0 it's available for python 3.6 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.5.0

Download the whl for the OS that you are working on and use pip install.